# loading a multidimensional array into view in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have a multidimensional array $result as

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [route_name] => MANJERI - NILAMBUR [departure_time] => 12:30 [arrival_time] => 13:00 ) 
[1] => Array ( [route_name] => MANJERI - PANDIKAD [departure_time] => 18:36 [arrival_time] => 19:05 ) )
```

i need to load this array into the view of codeigniter
here's my view code for the same

```
$this->load->view('bus_view', $result);
```

in the view I need to load the values into different columns of a table, and I used the following code

```
<table  align="center" width="60%" border="1" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5"
        style="position:relative; top:7px;">
            <thead></thead>
                <tr>
                <th>Trip Details</thead>
                <th>Departure</th>
                <th>Arrival</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php
                        foreach ($results as $result) {
                            echo "<tr>";
                            echo "<td>" .$result['route_name']. "</td>";
                            echo "<td>" .$result['departure_time']. "</td>";
                            echo "<td>" .$result['arrival_time']. "</td>";
                            echo "</tr>";
                        }
                ?> 
            </tbody>
```

but what I get as result is an error as follows

```
Undefined variable: results
```

I'm new to coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing your data the wrong way. Codeigniter read the array your giving to the view and associate every key as a new variable with its value as the value associates with the key.

So if you want to use `$results` in your view you will have to pass it this way :

```
$this->load->view('bus_view', ['results' => $results]);
```

And watch out you're giving `$result` to your view and using `$results` in it